# Facebook JS SDK issue with iPad CNA browser

Tags: ipad, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm writing an application which runs when a user tries to access a WiFi network and requires them to authenticate themselves. The router directs them to the site where they have some authentication options, one of which is through Facebook.

```
FB.login(function(response){
    if(response.authResponse){
        checkFBPermissions(response.authResponse.grantedScopes);
    }else{
        backToLoginOptions();
    }
},{
    scope: permissions,
    auth_type: authtype,
    return_scopes: true,
});
```

This all works fine on a laptop, android and even the new iPhone. On the iPad however (running iOS8), within the CNA browser (the browser that is launched automatically when connecting to the WiFi network) when the user hits login via FB they are taken to the FB login page within the same "tab" (I guess the CNA browser only ever has one tab) rather than opening a new window, and then after the user submits the Facebook login form it goes to a blank page. I guess this is because of the navigation away from the page (thus the JS code awaiting the response stops running).

We have a workaround which uses the "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" method but this doesn't seem to be supported by the new FB API and I was hoping to find a solution that uses the new standard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wifi network gateway is able to byPass the CNA browser. Then user is able to open browser manually.

Ruckus wireless provided this solution - bypassCNA=true

This will bypasses only iOS CNA page. Not android mini browser.